# .NET Gmail OAuth2 for multiple users

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We are building a solution that will need to access our customers Gmail accounts to read/send mail. On account signup, we'd have a pop-up for our customer to do Gmail auth page and then a backend process to periodically read their emails.

The documentation doesn't seem to cover this use case. For example https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth says that client tokens should be stored in client_secrets.json - what if we have 1000s of clients, what then?

Service accounts are for non-user info, but rather application data. Also, if I use the **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker** and the user has deleted access or the tokens have expired, I don't want my backend server app to pop open a web brower, as this seems to do.

I would imagine I could use IMAP/SMTP accomplish this, but I don't think it's a good idea to store those credentials in my db, nor do I think Google wants this either.

Is there a reference on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Sounds like you need to revisit the Google [OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#oauth-20-protocol). Client ID and secret are unique to each application type (Web App, Android, etc.). As for your use case, Service accounts is perfect for what you're looking for if you don't want to ask user to give consent every time they use your app. This is call "Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account". Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

Comment: Thanks for the response - but on the top of that page it says: "Typically, an application uses a service account when **the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.** For example, an application that uses Google Cloud Datastore for data persistence would use a service account to authenticate its calls to the Google Cloud Datastore API."

Comment: The part you linked to says: **Your application now has the authority to make API calls as users in your domain** These would random people not in my domain.

Comment: Ok. So, it sounds like you have users not within the same domain. If that's case, impersonation would not be feasible as users must be within the domain. Also, you should only have one client_secret per application. So, can you please give some more information about your use case?

Comment: Thanks - We are building a software solution that will be for sale to public. Part of the functionality would be similar to a mail client - read in emails and send messages. Eventually we'll add other providers as well in future. For security sakes, we prefer to do it via OAuth(2). So our clients would signup in a web page - give us auth to their account, then a backend app would process their messages and periodically send out new message on their behalf.

Comment: @Andres - Any suggestions for me? If need be, I don't need to use Google's .NET API. Thanks

Comment: Client secrets and client tokens are two different things. Client secrets belong to your application. A client token (access and refresh token) is a separate set of data that is linked between the user and your application. The library's default implementation for installed applications is to store the access/refresh token in a file under %AppData%, which is specific to the Windows user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @hurcane's answer more than likely is correct (haven't tried it out), this is what I got working over the past few days. I really didn't want to have to de/serialize data from the file to get this working, so I kinda mashed up this solution

1. Web app to get customer approval

   - Using AuthorizationCodeMvcApp from Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc and documentation
2. Store resulting access & refresh tokens in DB
3. Use AE.Net.Mail to do initial IMAP access with access token
4. Backend also uses AE.Net.Mail to access

   - If token has expired, then use refresh token to get new access token.

I've not done the sending part, but I presume SMTP will work similarly.

The code is based on SO & blog posts:

t = EF object containing token info

```
ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", t.EmailAddress, t.AccessToken, AuthMethods.SaslOAuth, 993, true);
```

To get an updated Access token (needs error handling) (uses the same API as step #1 above)

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["refresh_token"] = refresh;
                data["client_id"] = "(Web app OAuth id)";
                data["client_secret"] = "(Web app OAuth secret)";
                data["grant_type"] = "refresh_token";

                var response = wb.UploadValues(@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "POST", data);
                string Tokens = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                var token = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Tokens);
                at = token.access_token;
                return at;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this same situation. We are planning a feature where the user is approving access to send email on their behalf, but the actual sending of the messages is executed by a non-interactive process (scheduled task running on an application server).

I think the ultimate answer is a customized IAuthorizationCodeFlow that only supports access with an existing token, and will not execute the authorization process. I would probably have the flow simulate the response that occurs when a user clicks the Deny button on an interactive flow. That is, any need to get an authorization token will simply return a "denied" AuthorizationResult.

My project is still in the R&D phase, and I am not even doing a proof of concept yet. I am offering this answer in the hope that it helps somebody else develop a concrete solution.